# Can't install required packages for Ubuntu to build Android Open Source Project

Tags: android, ubuntu

I'm build Android Open Source Project on Ubuntu 10.0.4. I try to install required packages by execute below command (coppied from http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html) but I can't.

```
    sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
  zip curl zlib1g-dev libc6-dev lib32ncurses5-dev ia32-libs \
  x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib32readline5-dev lib32z-dev \
  libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32 tofrodos python-markdown \
  libxml2-utils xsltproc
```

The error message:

> E: Couldn't find package lib32ncurses5-dev
>
> E: Couldn't find package lib32readline5-dev
>
> E: Couldn't find package lib32z-dev
>
> E: Couldn't find package mingw32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution The list of required packages for building an Android OS is wrong. The correct packages are:

```
$ sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
zip curl zlib1g-dev libc6-dev lib64ncurses5-dev \ x11proto-core-dev
libx11-dev lib64readline5-dev lib64z-dev \ libgl1-mesa-dev
g++-multilib tofrodos
```

This is a mistake of Android Getting Started tutorial. Just want to share this.

Answer (score 0):

For 14.04 new packages are :

```
sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential zip curl zlib1g-dev libc6-dev lib64ncurses5-dev x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib64z-dev libgl1-mesa-dev tofrodos
```

Few removed. Not sure if more is required.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if he meant 14.04, but for 10.04 list would be for a 32-bit OS:

```
$  sudo apt-get install git gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential zip curl zlib1g-dev libc6-dev libncurses5-dev x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev libreadline5-dev libz-dev libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32 tofrodos python-markdown libxml2-utils xsltproc
```